# how make terminal full screen permanently?

Tags: command-line

I want to make my terminal full screen and not use <kbd>F11</kbd> all the time I open it. How can I do that? I cannot find any solution to it.

Comment: Which terminal emulator do you use? Please [edit] and clarify rather than using comments.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using gnome-terminal. you can do this from the settings.

1) Open a Terminal

2) Select  *profile preferences*  from the  *Edit Menu* .

3) Tick Use  *custom default terminal size*  or in some it is initial terminal size and enter a default size that is too large for the screen e.g. 250 columns and 100 rows.

Comment: A giant custom size is more like maximized than fullscreen. Use `gnome-terminal --full-screen` for the equivalent to pressing F11.

Comment: @egmont How come the manpage doesn't mention this option? oO

Comment: Mainstream `gnome-terminal` doesn't ship a manpage. Debian, and hence in turn Ubuntu adds its own one that lacks plenty of options and is not maintained. `--help` should be used instead as a reliable source.

Comment: And to even further complicate the situation, `gnome-terminal` is a shell script wrapper in front of the binary `gnome-terminal.real` in Ubuntu. I don't know if/how it passes `--help` through to the binary.